`Cannot GET /callback/` error with the Spotify Web Playback SDK
I've been trying to follow the guide to create a web player in React with Node.js based on this: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/howtos/web-app-player but I keep getting told that the path /callback can't be made a GET request to. This is very strange since I basically just copied what the documentation gives me and even on changing the values in the redirect uri field in the Dashboard I can't get it to work, no matter how many variations of http://localhost:3000/auth/callback I try. I'm able to get the code returned to me in the form of the url http://localhost:3000/auth/callback/?code=AQDe8jEv0Ugqtopb7UxMD50bNxDoSrs5sAOtxq553dRBKIvlWb2lkyrwpjU1JCAmyypOJT2Yk4zhOh-yJcUK-T6wPeaiKYpQWnzSV_JGYTTJZd3VWh76_blgBKJFyr8batBFV757PD8NGUfK7yi7nCYzY7lH--SjE-kMLB5HliMqTvatD1xbM1nVKk7arWDXTYijYhgfZEsx_JXcgSsekuo8JE8bVqnDjVuxq29lctqARozZQKP_&state=k0GvJaa9SKQ9nQOy however this renders Cannot GET /callback/.
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const request = require('request');

const port = 5000

let access_token = ' ';
var spotify_redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback/';

dotenv.config()

let generateRandomString = function (length) {
    let text = '';
    let possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
  };
  

let spotify_client_id = process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID
let spotify_client_secret = process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET

let app = express();

app.get('/auth/token', (req, res) => {
    res.json(
       {
          access_token: access_token
       })
});  

app.get('/auth/login', (req, res) => {
    let scope = "streaming \ user-read-email \ user-read-private";
    let state = generateRandomString(16);

    let auth_query_parameters = new URLSearchParams({
        response_type: "code",
        client_id: spotify_client_id,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: spotify_redirect_uri,
        state: state
      });

      res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?' + auth_query_parameters.toString());
});

app.get('/auth/callback', (req, res) => {
    let code = req.query.code;
    console.log("=========================CODE RETURNED==================", code);

  let authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    form: {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: spotify_redirect_uri,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    },
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (Buffer.from(spotify_client_id + ':' + spotify_client_secret).toString('base64')),
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log("Spotify returned access_token:", body.access_token);
      access_token = body.access_token;

      res.redirect(`/`);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

Anybody know what I can do to fix this? There is nothing in the documentation whatsoever pertaining to this issue. Also note that I tried to whitelist even https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/? but it doesn't work. Note that the server runs on port 5000 where as the React files are rendered on the port 3000. Also, the route /auth/token never returns anything except an empty access_token field.
